# Specifying color of NA raster values in levelplot (R package rasterVis)

Tags: r, levelplot, rastervis

How can I assign a specific color to NA values of a raster when plotting it with the levelplot function from R-package rasterVis? I am searching for a similar functionality as "colNA".

Comment: Examples generally prompt more interest than request to construct entire examples.  Often you can just start with code cut from the help pages.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`levelplot` uses the background color to display the `NA` values. Thus, you have to modify this color using `panel.background`.

```
library(rasterVis)

myTheme <- BTCTheme()
myTheme$panel.background$col = 'gray' 

f <- system.file("external/test.grd", package="raster")
r <- raster(f)
levelplot(r, par.settings = myTheme)
```

[image: levelplot with background color]